# Axiom of set theory wanted

Tags: elementary-set-theory, axioms

Which axiom of set theory forbids a mathematical object to be an element of a set and not be an element of the very same set?

Comment: Am I correctly interpreting your question in that you are asking for an axiom asserting that $\forall a,b: \neg ( a \in b \wedge \neg (a \in b))$ if $a$ and $b$ are sets?

Comment: In most developments, this isn't an axiom of set theory, but rather an axiom of the first-order logic in which the set theory is formulated.

Comment: @G.Chiusole Apart from $a$ not necessarily being a set, yes.

Comment: I have posted the comment as an answer to notify users browsing the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Nate Eldredge has noted, the axiom will not be given in the set theory, but rather in the underlying (probably first-order) logic. In general, the assertion is given as $\neg (\psi \wedge \neg \psi)$, where $\psi$ is some predicate, basically saying that nothing can be true and false at the same time. It is referred to as the [law of non-contradiction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_thought#The_law_of_non-contradiction) and is part of classical logics.

Comment: Can _first-order logic_ be referred to as the foundation where mathematic is built upon?

Comment: Yes, to some extend. Most set theories (ZF, NBG, MK,...) are build upon *first order* logic. In general, mathematics is founded on logic. However, we may not restrict ourselves to *first order* logic, depending on what we define as mathematics in the first place. But that would be more of a philosophical issue. In short, the answer is yes.

Answer (score 2):

As noted above, the axiom you're looking for is the law of non-contradiction. This is a logical axiom. In fact, it is an axiom of classical and intuitionistic logic, and, by implication, of classical mathematics and constructive mathematics, respectively.

It is not, however, an axiom of paraconsistent logic. Systems of paraconsistent logic are, in some sense, tolerant toward contradiction. More precisely, they do not (necessarily) 'explode' in the presence of a contradiction of the form ($\phi$ $\land$ $\neg$$\phi$).

Unsurprisingly, there is also paraconsistent set theory. The logical axioms of systems falling in this category will not include the law of non-contradiction in full generality. However, while I am no expert on the topic of paraconsistent logic and mathematics, I would still expect that even in a paraconsistent set theory, $(a \in b) \land (a \notin b)$ is not a valid proposition. But then (unlike in the classical case) its invalidity **may** have to be determined by the non-logical axioms of the theory.

Regarding your question as to whether logic is the foundation of mathematics:

Logic certainly does play an important *foundational role* in mathematics. For one, ZFC – which is considered by many to the proper foundational theory of mathematics – is 'built on' first-order predicate logic.

However, logic is not *the foundation of* mathematics as it does not provide any mathematical content. The axioms of first-order logic, for instance, are all tautologies. They have no content, if you will. In particular, they do not postulate the existence of any mathematical objects. Thus, they give us nothing to 'build' mathematics *from*.

Set theory, on the other hand, does just that. The axioms of ZFC tell us that there is an empty set, that for sets *a*, *b*, the set {*a*, *b*} exists, that an infinite set exists, and so on. From the 'material' that ZFC gives us, the rest of mathematics can be 'built'.

Note, however, - and this relates back to your initial question - that how much mathematical content you can extract from your theory's mathematical axioms *is* to a certain degree dictated by your choice of logic.

For instance, many theorems of classical ZFC are not provable within set theories built on intuitionistic logic (e.g., CZF or IZF). Namely, all those theorems whose proofs involve an application of the law of excluded middle or of the law of double negation elimination. These laws are axioms of classical logic but not of intuitionistic logic.

Comment: Arguably, *all* mathematical theorems *are* tautologies... "If such and such, then such and such".

Comment: Still (in theory) they all trace back to ZFC (or PA, or what have you). And those axioms certainly are not tautologies, are they? Or would you say that "There is an empty set." is a tautology?

Comment: If ZFC is consistent, then ZFC proves the existence and uniqueness of a set without elements.

Comment: ZFC also proves the Axiom of Choice. Does that make the Axiom of Choice a tautology? Within ZFC, yes. Without, no.

Comment: No. But it makes "ZFC proves AC" a tautology.

Comment: Again, within ZFC, though. Could you elaborate a bit on what your point is? Are you questioning the possibility of distinguishing, a priori, between what is logical (tautologous) and what is non-logical (contentual)?

Comment: _paraconsistent_ set theory? :D Cool.